# If a number is not transcendental, is it algebraic?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, discrete-mathematics, proof-verification, proof-writing

I know all algebraic numbers aren't transcendental, but not sure if the claim holds the other way around.

Comment: In short, yes. A number which is not algebraic is _by definition_ transcendental. Conversely, a number which is not transcendental must be algebraic.

Comment: Is there a "degree" of trascendence for numbers?

Comment: It's one instance where opposites do not have opposite-sounding names. Other instances:  In set theory a cardinal is either regular or singular but not both.... An  integer is odd or even but not both. (No one calls the number  1 "uneven".)

Comment: @ZhuoranHe . Yes.  For example there are Liouville numbers, a (small) subset of the real transcendentals.

Comment: @DanielWainfleet FYI in some languages this is different.  For example, in Russian "odd" (for numbers) is simply "even" with a negative prefix.

Answer (score 0):

The standard definition of an algebraic element of (say) a field extension is that it is the root of some polynomial over the base field. A transcendental number is a number which does not arise in such a way. For instance, $\sqrt{2}\not\in \mathbf{Q}$, but $\sqrt{2}$ is the root of the polynomial $x^2-2\in \mathbf{Q}[x]$. As such, we say that $\sqrt{2}$ is algebraic. Indeed, the properties of being algebraic or transcendental are mutually exclusive. So, if $z$ is not transcendental, it is algebraic and conversely.

It can be shown that a number such as $\pi$ is not algebraic over $\mathbf{Q}$. That is, there does not exist a polynomial with coefficients in $\mathbf{Q}$ so that $\pi$ is a solution. Obviously, this does depend on which field we choose, since $\pi$ is a root of $x-\pi\in \mathbf{R}[x]$. On the other hand, $\sqrt{-1}$ is algebraic over $\mathbf{R}$.